# How to embed Facebook Questio-n in website?

Tags: facebook, embed

Is there any easy way to display single public Facebook question in my website (so it looks same as in Facebook)?

I would like to embed a public Facebook question in website. I can get the question and the answers using graph.facebook.com but that way I would need access token and layout code for the looks.

Javascript and PHP solutions are fine for me. It should look something like
https://i.stack.imgur.com/L44XB.png

(Questio-n in Title is because SO doesn't allow word question in title)

Answer (score 0):

**Facebook simply does not provide a plugin to embed questions**.  What you'd have to do is recreate the functionality (as best you can) to emulate the questions on Facebook.

Its quite a daunting task but it **is** possible.  This great site offers a great starting point -

http://ckrack.github.com/fbootstrapp/

Here is how it looks more or less -

[image]